# How to remove a specific package from yocto

Tags: yocto, imx6

I am building yocto for a specific hardware (imx6 saber-sdb from nxp). I want to remove a particular (chromium) package from the build process. So that chromium package will not be downloaded, compiled and will not be part of the target image as well.

Can somebody suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 15):

Below is how you can remove chromium package from your image.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += "chromium"
```

The other way is `PACKAGE_EXCLUDE`. Have a look [here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/current/ref-manual/variables.html#term-PACKAGE_EXCLUDE)

Comment: PACKAGE_EXCLUDE: "Support does not exist for DEB",i.e. when deb packages are used (as we have e.g. in company where I work)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit **image recipe** and remove (comment out) line that should be located there:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = “ chromium”
```

(it could be also in **IMAGE_INSTALL +=** ), take a look [here](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-95059).

The **image recipe** file is bitbake file with the name that you use to build your image, you should be able to find it in some meta folder, e.g. *meta-<>/meta-fsl-demos/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-gui-sdk.bb*.

Note that **IMAGE_INSTALL** is not recommended when used in build directory  *conf/local.conf* (and it looks it just doesn't work as far as I have seen). That is why the recommended way is to either modify existing **image recipe** or clone/modify it.